# Remove automatic gift

Tags: intershop

I would like to know if someone has already done a feature in order to remove an automatic gift in the basket.
The discount rule is like

```
one computer offers a mouse
```

Thanks for your comprehension.
I read the documentation but I didn't find anything on this specific subject.

Is it possible to put the gift's quantity to 0 to simulate a "remove" ?